# How to understand your pages are being requested under facebook or not inside masterpage asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, iframe, detection

I am going to add my website to the facebook as an application. Facebook do not allow 3 rd party ads so i have to remove them. I want to remove ads for only facebook visitors. So i want to understand whether page is being called under facebook as an iframe or not. How can i do that with javascript ? Thank you.

I can also use jquery.

asp.net 4.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect either users open my Facebook app in iframe or direct url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202402/how-do-i-detect-either-users-open-my-facebook-app-in-iframe-or-direct-url)

Comment: not answering my question. i have to check at every page request whether it is under facebook application or not. and i will not allow other websites iframing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following detects if your page is viewed in an iframe:

```
if (window.location != window.parent.location){
      //you are in an iframe
}
else {
      //you are NOT in an iframe
}
```

[EDIT]
If you want also to specify that the iframe is in facebook then you could try this:

```
if(window.name != "") {
  //We are on Facebook
} 
else
{
  //We are just in the normal browser window
}
```

I haven't tested this, just came across a few weeks ago [here](http://www.blakes-site.co.uk/blog/23/Detect-if-page-is-within-Facebook-iframe-or-not-Javascript/)

Comment: the point is understanding whether it is facebook or not. because i will not allow other iframing websites

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG see the edits in my reply. However, i haven't tested the (second) sample code

Comment: i am trying at localhost and it is empty. the window.name

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG so it seems working. If `window.name` is empty you are not in facebook. If `window.name` is NOT empty you are in facebook. I just tested it.
:)

Comment: you know some other things also may make window.name not empty. so it is not a proper solution. what i want is only allowing iframing inside facebook and also understanding whether it is under facebook iframing or not

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I can't figure any alternative solution to achieve what you want. I'm not sure, maybe it's not achivable elsehow :s
Maybe you could achieve something better using the above script to check if you are in an iframe and combine it with some server-side script - checking HTTP_REFERER for example - if you are willing to take this risk ;)

Comment: well i will give this a try soon :)